# Problem with Matcher in the Hamcrest library

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, libraries, hamcrest

I'm following along with a learning course for Java and the person uses the `contains()` method in the Hamcrest library. Here's what the code looks like

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class ShipmentTest
{
    private Shipment shipment = new Shipment();

    @Test
    public void shouldAddItems() throws Exception
    {
        shipment.add(door);
        shipment.add(window);

        assertThat(shipment, contains(door, window));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReplaceItems() throws Exception
    {
        shipment.add(door);
        shipment.add(window);

        shipment.replace(door, floorPanel);

        assertThat(shipment, contains(floorPanel, window));
    }
}
```

I'm using Eclipse, and it doesn't recognize the `contains()` method, since it's part of the Hamcrest library. However, when I try to implement it, Eclipse doesn't find `Matchers` in the Hamcrest library. It finds `Matcher`, `CoreMatchers`, and `MatcherAssert`, but not `Matchers`, which should have the `contains()` method. I've downloaded the jar file for version 1.3 of hamcrest, but even when I include it in the build path, it still does not find `Matcher`. What should I be doing?

Comment: according to hamcrest 1.3 javadoc there seems to be a Matcher interface but it should be implemented by a concrete class http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/
i couldn't find the method *contains* in the interface

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say contains is in Matchers, not the Matcher interface, but my IDE doesn't find Matchers. I've updated the post so that it's correct now.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find it either, but I only had the **org.hamcrest-core** jar on the path. Then I realised that the Matchers class is in the **org.hamcrest-library** jar!